# Android - Selector with border color?

Tags: android

I have a seelctor that I use on my radioButtons. I need to set a border on each one. Why does the selector below not apply border?

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:exitFadeDuration="@integer/short_anim_time">

  <item android:drawable="@color/orange"
      android:state_pressed="true"/>

  <item android:drawable="@color/orange"
      android:state_checked="true"/>

  <item android:drawable="@color/white"
      android:state_focused="true"/>

  <item android:drawable="@color/white"/>


  <item>
    <shape>
      <stroke
          android:width="2dp"
          android:color="@color/orange"/>

      <padding
          android:left="@dimen/gap"
          android:top="@dimen/gap"
          android:right="@dimen/gap"
          android:bottom="@dimen/gap"/>
    </shape>
  </item>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple,

put your border in it's own file.

then add

```
  android:background="@drawable/border"
```

That's how I got it to work with my image views..

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_icon"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:src="@drawable/foo" />
```